# How to rename a series in Google Sheets chart?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

By default, a Google Sheets chart will use the first row as the the name of the Series. But if you are selecting a range in the middle of the table (for example, rows 38-100), then you can't use the first row as the name. You have to uncheck `Use row 38 as headers`.

[image]

In that situation, how do you name / rename the Series?

Answer (score 15):

Make sure your graph shows the legend.  Then, double click on the legend symbol you want to add a name to and type your name in the "Text Label" box in the menu that appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Chart editor and change the value for 'X-axis' to select data from the header range.
[image]